# Code for .zshrc or .bash_profile that sets jupyter notebook Alias to type in terminal as shortcut jn

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook, alias, zsh

I develop in Anaconda3 and Jupyter Notebook with Python for my coding environment on Mac OSX, with Visual Studio Code.

I typically type **jupyter notebook** numerous times throughout the day to launch new instances, yet this is inefficient for keystrokes.

I am looking to write a script or alias inside my .zshrc file for OhMyZsh (similar to .bash_profile) that will let me simply type **jn**, as desired to save time in Terminal to launch a new jupyter notebook instance.

Comment: Kindly requesting to determine why this post was down-voted?  I am learning to be more effective on Stackoverflow, and I had done research through the ohmyzsh documentation, without seeing much Alias documentation, so thought this question would be helpful both for my knowledge and others in the future on Stackoverflow.  Kindly requesting thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly

```
alias jn="jupyter notebook"
```

Though, I would suggest using a function that you can define a notebook directory

```
function jn() {
    local notedir="$1"
    # Add extra logic here to give a standard directory, if no param given 
    jupyter notebook "$notedir"
}
```

Sidenote: Bundling a Docker container with all your needed kernels and combining that with this function allows for good portability, for example sharing notebooks with others